# How can I spawn a child process that starts an electron app and then kill it while keeping the parent process alive?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a main process that launches (spawn) an electron app (child) and I am trying kill it while keeping parent alive after a while. I always only kill the parent and the only thing that I have achieved after reading through a lot of articles (also on stackoverflow) is that I kill both of them. But I need to keep the parent alive. I want to be able to kill a child process that does not respond anymore or craches.

I tried to fork but also to spawn.
I tried all of this within the parent.js (code below):

Kills both:

```
process.kill(-script.pid);
```

kills parent only:

```
kill(-script.pid, SIGKILL);
```

kills parent only (script is the child from script = spawn(...)):

```
script.stdin.pause();
script.kill();
```

parent.js:

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

console.log('main process started.');

let script = spawn('npm', ["start"], {detached: true});

setTimeout(function(){

  //This one kills both
  process.kill(-script.pid);

  }, 3000);
```

child.js:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('cd $HOME/Desktop/Myapp && npm start');
```

I want the parent to be always alive and kill the child process whenever it wants to.
I know it's pretty basic but even after intensive research and reading I just can't make it work.

Does it have to do with Electron maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution myself. For those who are interested.

I use these two modules:

```
const findProcess = require('find-process');
const ps = require('ps-node');
```

I basically use findProcess to find the PIDs by name and then I use ps to kill all the processes associated with this.

```
findProcess('name', "Electron")
    .then(function (list) {

      for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){

        console.log(list[i].pid);
        pidToKill = list[i].pid;
        pidToKill = pidToKill.toString();

        ps.kill( pidToKill, {
          signal: 'SIGKILL',
          timeout: 10,  // will set up a ten seconds timeout if the killing is not successful
        }, function(){});

      }
    }, function (err) {
      console.log(err.stack || err);
    });
```

Either this helps you as well or you have a better solution. 
If there are better solutions then I am glad to hear about them.

Thanks